I can't click on the run option when i enter my VM on eclipse

when I try to run the code i get this error:
Error: Could not find or load main class 
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: 

I have tried removing and re-adding the build-path, i also uninstalled the old java version which was 17.02 and get the 22. installed the latest javafx-sdk 22 jars but still the problem remains

You should provide the complete stack trace.  A ClassNotFoundException will tell what which class was not found.  Ensure you can get a hello world app running by following instructions at openjfx.io.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

For the brand new Java 22, Eclipse 2024-03 with Java 22 Support for Eclipse 2024-03 (4.31) would be required. But better stick to Java 21 for which long term support is provided in contrast to Java 22. The fact that you specified VM arguments indicates you doing something wrong. Please follow the JavaFX documentation for "JavaFX and Eclipse". If your project is configured correctly, you can simply click on the Run button without having to edit the launch configuration.

The launch configuration is telling you that the Main tab isn't specifying a class to run.
